# How significant are faster SD cards for raspberry pi?

Tags: sd-card, storage

Assuming we are using something more IO-heavy than a pi-hole. For example if we have a database running and a web service running, will we notice differences with different Cards?

Does somebody tested different SD cards on their pi? I want to understand the practical differences between a 10 Euro SD and a 50-100 Euro SD. Will it even be noticeable?

Comment: there's plenty of benchmarks if you just search for them, and the difference is very noticable - a poor SD card will make the pi experience unbearable

Comment: As jaromanda says search around for `"raspberry pi" "sd card" benchmark` and you'll find bunches of stuff.  Notice that the speed maxes out at a certain point (depending on model) -- there's no point in getting a card faster than that.  If you've never done this before also keep in mind there is a difference between read and write speeds.  For general purposes the read is more important but they tend to go hand in hand, write being slower.